# How to use esttab when I do ivreg2

Tags: stata

How can I use `esttab` to report underidentification test and weak identification test (both stages) after `ivreg2`?

```
ivreg2 y (x = z), savefirst
est store A

esttab _ivreg2_x A using iv.tex, se replace stat(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

From an econometric perspective, I do not think you should be able to compute these test statistics separately for the two stages.

```
eststo clear
eststo: ivreg2 y (x = z), first savefirst savefprefix(fs_1)
esttab est1 fs_1* using iv.tex, se replace /// 
       stat(N idstat widstat, labels("N" "Underidentification" "Weak identification"))
```